# Which fields does immediate take in mips architecture?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

If we compare R-type and I-type instructions of MIPS. Then if we look at it and tell that in I-type instructions which fields of R-type and converted to immediate then which fields will they be?
The fields in R-type which are used to store immediate in I-type are rd, shamt and function. So should we say that the
first 3 fields of R-type are used to store the immediate or should we say that the last three fields of R-type are used to store the immediate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this question you have to look at the instruction format for I-Type and R-Type instructions to see the intersection of the fields for the immediate field in I-Type instructions and the corresponding fields (according to location) in R-Type instructions:

I-Type instructions have this format:

- bits 31-26: opcode
- bits 25-21: source register (`rs`)
- bits 20-16: target register (`rt`)
- bits 15-0 : immediate

and R-Type instructions have this format:

- bits 31-26: opcode
- bits 25-21: source register (`rs`)
- bits 20-16: target register (`rt`)
- bits 15-11: destination register (`rd`)
- bits 10-6 : shift ammount (`shamt`)
- bits 5-0  : function

Therefore the bits used to store the immediate on I-Type instructions are used to hold the destination register (`rd`), shift ammount (`shamt`) and `function`

Comment: that is true but the question is should we say that the function, shamt and rd are the first 3 fields or the last 3 fields of an r-type instruction?. Because I am saying these are the first three fields cause of the 0-15 bits.. but my instructor says they are the last three... and I really don't understand how are they the last three fields.

Comment: @RanaTallal: It depends on whether you look the word (32 bits) from left to right or from right to left. If you look at them from right to left being bit 0 the rightmost (as I usually do) then they are the first 3 fields. If you look at them from left to right then they are the last three fields. What's important here is that they are the fields located in bits 15-0